# Testing an overriden equals method

Tags: java, testing, equals, hashcode

I'm reading J. Bloch's effective Java and needed to brush up the `equals`/`hashCode` contracts and relationships.

I have the following JavaBeans class:

```
public class MyJavaBean{

    private int id;

    private Properties fItem;  //Enumeration type

    private String value;

    private Rule rule;         //Enumeration type

    private int fId;

    //GET, SET

        @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(!(o instanceof MyJavaBean))
            return false;
        MyJavaBeanv = (MyJavaBean) o;
        return (fItem == null ? v.fItem == null : fItem.equals(v.fItem)) && 
                (value == null ? v.value == null : value.equals(v.value)) && 
                (rule == null ? v.rule == null : rule.equals(v.rule)) && 
                fId == v.fId && id == v.id;
    }

    @Override 
    public int hashCode(){
        int result = 17;
        if(fItem != null)
            result = 31 * result + fItem.hashCode();
        if(value != null)
            result = 31 * result +  value.hashCode();
        if(rule != null)
            result = 31 * result + rule.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + fId;
        result = 31 * result + id;
        return result;
    }
}
```

He also suggest we write unitTests to make sure the contracts are actually satisfied. Here is what he said(italic-bold emphasize mine):

> **When you are finished writing your  equals  method, ask yourself three**
>   **questions: Is it symmetric? Is it transitive? Is it consistent?**  And
>   don’t just ask yourself; ***write unit tests*** to check that these
>   properties hold!

So, I can't imagine how to write unit test for that pretty straightforward case. Well, I'd write something like that:

```
public class MyTest{

    //Each pair consists of the equals object
    private Map<MyJavaBean, MyJavaBean> equalValueMap;

    @Before
    public void init(){
        //initializing the map, using ThredLocalRandom 
        //to get ints and enums randomly
    }

    @Test
    public void testReflexive(){
        for(MyJavaBean fiv: equalValueMap.keySet()){
            Assert.assertEquals(fiv.equals(fiv), true);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testSymmetric(){
        for(MyJavaBean fiv: equalValueMap.keySet()){
            Assert.assertEquals(equalValueMap.get(fiv).equals(fiv), true);
            Assert.assertEquals(fiv.equals(equalValueMap.get(fiv)), true);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testHashCode(){
        for(FilterItemValue fiv: equalFilterValueMap.keySet()){
            Assert.assertEquals(equalFilterValueMap.get(fiv).hashCode(), fiv.hashCode());
        }
    }
}
```

But I think such tests just waste the build-time, because of their simplicity. Is it worthy to write tests for the methods for simple JavaBeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO! You can safely skip the tests for `equals()` and `hashCode()` if they are generated by an IDE / some helping library you trust.

Although, if you're really doing some complex things and worry if these methods may not behave as desired in runtime, it might be worth spending time and writing a simple test.